# how to run multiple jobs simultaneously in bash shell

Tags: multithreading, bash, shell

I would like to run the same bash script multiple times on multiple ID's.

Here is the script that i was talking about:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/diag/software/bin:$PATH
cd /diag/cloud/udevisetty/RIL_stuff/Block_01
fq_dir="/diag/cloud/udevisetty/RIL_stuff/Block_01"
map_dir="/diag/cloud/udevisetty/RIL_stuff/mapping/"

for RIL in $(cat /diag/cloud/udevisetty/RIL_stuff/Block_01/test.txt); do
      for lane in 01; do
            perl /diag/cloud/udevisetty/RIL_stuff/Block_01/bwa_tophat_final.pl \
            --threads 12 \
            --out $map_dir/$RIL.$lane \
            --bwa_n 0.04 \
            --bwa_db /diag/home/udevisetty/db/Brapa_sequence_v1.5.fa \
            --fq $fq_dir/$RIL/*fq \
            --fq_id $RIL.$lane \
            --bowtie_db /diag/home/udevisetty/db/Brapa_sequence_v1.5.fa \
            --ref_fa /diag/home/udevisetty/db/Brapa_sequence_v1.5.fa \
            --ref_id Brapa_v1.5 \
            > $map_dir/$RIL.$lane.bwa_tophat.log \
            2> $map_dir/$RIL.$lane.bwa_tophat.err
done;
done
```

My test file contains the following ID's

```
RIL_251
RIL_21
RIL_211
RIL_136
RIL_66
RIL_155
```

But right now all it is doing is going through each ID in test.txt file (since it is a 'for' loop) and then executing the script one at a time. However i would like to run all of the IDs simultaneously on 12 threads each. How can i modify my script to do that?

Comment: Add `&` to the end of the command to tell the shell to run it in the background. Also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor for why you don't want to be looping over your file contents like that.

Comment: Do you mean add `&` at the end of this `perl /diag/cloud/udevisetty/RIL_stuff/Block_01/bwa_tophat_final.pl`?

Comment: Yes, as the end of that perl command line in the loop. After `2> $map_dir/$RIL.$lane.bwa_tophat.err`.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing the issues it identifies -- there are a bunch of unrelated bugs hiding around here.

Comment: Technically, by the way, everything here is a subprocess, not a thread; threads share a single process, and bash doesn't support them at all.

Comment: use & to put the process background and use *wait* command to wait the background process to finish.

Comment: Even after putting `&` and adding `wait` at the end it is only running one ID at a time. `2> $map_dir/$RIL.$lane.bwa_tophat.err &
wait`

Answer (score 0):

A contrived exampled illustrating how to do this with 'xargs':

```
root# cat id.txt | xargs -n 1 -P 3 ./script.sh
id2
id1
id4
id3
id5
id7
id6
```

Contents of id.txt, notice it's ordered.

```
root# cat id.txt
id1
id2
id3
id4
id5
id6
id7
```

Script contents:

```
root# cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

You can also use GNU Parallel if available [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

Comment: Have you read the source to GNU Parallel? It's a mess, with a huge amount of incidental complexity stemming from rarely-used (read: rarely tested) functionality. Not pretty at all. `xargs -P` is solid, though, if on a platform where it's supported.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize:

```
while read -u 3 -r line; do
  process "$line" &
done 3< input.txt
```

This follows the [BashFAQ #001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) best-practice approach for reading lines from the file (using FD 3 to avoid reassigning the descriptor for stdin), and uses the `&` operator to background each process.